# Co-ordinate of touch location is zero

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, coordinates

I am struggling to get the coordinates based on touch.

For simplicity I have created a new Project using swift and a sprite kit game - the default spinning spaceship one.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")

        sprite.xScale = 0.5
        sprite.yScale = 0.5
        sprite.position = location
        **NSLog("position x %f and y %f", location.x, location.y)**
        let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration: 1)

        sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))

        self.addChild(sprite)
    }
}
```

All I added to the project was the `NSLog` line to output the coordinates of the touch. But all I get in the output is `0` for `x` and `y`.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: try `println("position x \(location.x) and y \(location.y)")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert whatever the `location` object is returning for variables `x` and `y` to a `Float` if you want to print the coordinates using `NSLog` with the `%f` formatter.

```
NSLog("position x %f and y %f", Float(location.x), Float(location.y))
```

If you aren't dead set on using `NSLog`, you can also do what Okapi suggested in his comment and use `println`. Both mechanisms work.

```
println("x:\(location.x)  y:\(location.y)")
```